# Python webscraping, TypeError: Object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am facing the following error:

`TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

not to sure what not subscriptable means in this case.

**Code:**

```
def get_detail_data(soup):
    # title
    title = soup.find('h1', id='itemTitle')  # .get_text().replace('Details about', '').strip()

def get_page(url):
    response = requests.get(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    return soup

import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_page(url):
    response = requests.get(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    return soup


def get_detail_data(soup):
    # title
    title = soup.find('h1', id='itemTitle')  #.get_text().replace('Details about', '').strip()
    # price
    price = soup.find('span', id='prcIsum')  #.get_text().replace('AU', '').strip()

    # items sold

    item_sold = soup.find('a', class_="vi-txt-underline")  #.get_text()

    data = {
        'title' : title,
        'price' : price,
        'total sold' : item_sold
    }

    print(data)


def get_index_data(soup):
    try:
        links = soup.find_all('a', class_='s-item__link')
    except:
        links = []

    urls = [item.get('href') for item in links]

    return urls



def write_csv(data, url):
    with open('output.csv', 'a') as csvfile:

        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)


        row = [data['title'], data['price'], data['currency'], data['total_sold'], url]


        writer.writerow(row)

def main():
    url = 'https://www.ebay.com.au/itm/Hand-SANITISER-99-9-KILLS-BACTERIA-ANTI-50ML-BOTTLE-75-ALCOHOL-SANITIZER-200ml/223945948963?_trkparms=ispr%3D1&hash=item342437ff23:g:khMAAOSw5nxeacjv&enc=AQAEAAACQBPxNw%2BVj6nta7CKEs3N0qUoq7S6Ltgt8Jng9mz0btUpqaGsjuB%2Bw2rCklIv%2Bj5pwMy36btYuxspTnsKATiZNuni34NVo2hqJMA85Zsfh52qeLpStR2JSrB7%2BHtQKIg1GlO0teUIaInCJRj1YyJww7S0d8fNxToouu39f6jqsTX2CTevhqUsDKj07Pb7yvpgvygG2NI%2FIen%2B7HiWcQH8TGJMpENBEfw1gDm2cP%2FUQ9L%2F1CH0Pfra%2B1X7JKUcSAH0K1w3BR0JeplFKIprfxvScPG4e%2FBK0i2ybiBu4kdQG4j0KjhD%2FYzSklR2OJDwU10HEDq%2F4N64VAV9e5B%2BLK3eSWpOAuDvo1gw8aSWzJu1cxsEKlE4WsINTkOF0Mdw%2B0cPQpSc8xG6apVjRlDEVe7AI5i3TU%2Bchbf1%2B8N6UbUTxzCahnCkweV%2B3MGEsY3LnTs0PcXC7eOzKY8YGVYT6veG3TVTJEKVM5lR2D1eySvpTs3z189uqpJPjZyXr7IC5uE%2Fy96%2FDtEGvCNeYrkgqIIlYrJaNj2LDz%2BrTOY%2BMiC9l5aeP2XhHoKwuYj8ffGDkZ6JkZPB%2FXH69tfGYDDznVOaM%2FfdXBUtqIGwNotjRCAzOTgSEJh4J4kJwtTqM%2Fd4AJQfJa7FLIVioLOepu9B7xELx7aHL0qbysGYbACDQmk4o7Iexs9haCG9iA1t4x0MhBHgv%2FM%2BryctScf4YwwygHHvYqJ8UXmoT%2FRIw53K%2Fu91rlBzIJa6jkuVtMvmxVP%2BKjajfA%3D%3D&checksum=223945948963e6cc117bdb704be9a8d20e2bc78dd0a8'

    products = get_index_data(get_page(url))

    for link in products:
        data = get_detail_data(get_page(link))
        write_csv(data, link)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Error from console:**

```
MacBook-Pro:ebayWebScraper ThomasHunt$ python3 app.py
{'title': None, 'price': None, 'total sold': None}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 69, in <module>
    main()
  File "app.py", line 67, in main
    write_csv(data, link)
  File "app.py", line 55, in write_csv
    row = [data['title'], data['price'], data['currency'], data['total_sold'], url]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Here is the data printed from the loop:

```
{'title': None, 'price': None, 'total sold': None}
None
{'title': None, 'price': None, 'total sold': None}
None
{'title': <h1 class="it-ttl" id="itemTitle" itemprop="name"><span class="g-hdn">Details about   </span>Hand SANITI
SER 99.9% KILLS BACTERIA 50ML BOTTLE 75% ALCOHOL SANITIZER EB</h1>, 'price': <span class="notranslate" content="U
$5.71" id="prcIsum" itemprop="price" style="">AU $5.71 each</span>, 'total sold': <a class="vi-txt-underline" href
="https://offer.ebay.com.au/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewBidsLogin&amp;item=264665546863&amp;rt=nc&amp;_trksid=p2047675.l2
564">10 sold</a>}
None
{'title': <h1 class="it-ttl" id="itemTitle" itemprop="name"><span class="g-hdn">Details about   </span>Hand SANITI
SER 99.9% KILLS BACTERIA 50ML BOTTLE 75% ALCOHOL SANITIZER EB</h1>, 'price': <span class="notranslate" content="U
$5.71" id="prcIsum" itemprop="price" style="">AU $5.71 each</span>, 'total sold': <a class="vi-txt-underline" href

="https://offer.ebay.com.au/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewBidsLogin&amp;item=264665546863&amp;rt=nc&amp;_trksid=p2047675.l2
564">10 sold</a>}
None
{'title': <h1 class="it-ttl" id="itemTitle" itemprop="name"><span class="g-hdn">Details about   </span>75% Alcohol
 Gel Hand Sanitiser 50ml 99.9% Kill Bacteria 1/2/3/5 Bottle Sanitizer</h1>, 'price': <span class="notranslate" con
tent="1.09" id="prcIsum" itemprop="price" style="">GBP 1.09</span>, 'total sold': <a class="vi-pop-drkgry vi-txt-u
nderline" href="https://offer.ebay.com.au/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewBidsLogin&amp;item=402160479994&amp;rt=nc&amp;_trks
id=p2047675.l2564">115 sold</a>}
```

Comment: What is the "ignore: ..." part about? Is that your text, it is really confusing. Like someone did not know how to add a comment and edited your post.

Comment: You did change the posting, but not according to the posting guidelines I cited.  Please do so.  The output above alternates `None` with meaningful values.  However, since the output isn't labeled, and you still failed to post the MVE to produce this output, I'm not sure whether the `None` values are `data` results -- any of which would cause the run-time message.  Also, please include the full error message, not merely the header text.  This would include the Traceback from your MVE, *not* from the full code example.

Comment: Also note that "Nonetype is not subscriptable" is an easy look-up, with many references already on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do minimal diagnosis.  The problem is almost certainly with the results of your loop:

```
for link in products:
    data = get_detail_data(get_page(link))
    write_csv(data, link)
```

Check the value of `data` you pass in at each call; it appears that one of them is `None`, which will cause the given error: `['title']` is a subscript.  We can't tell, because you neglected to give us the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example); you'll have to take it from here.